# GetMapping API in elasticsearch 8 - getting too many fields

Tags: elasticsearch

in elasticsearch 7 I used to get my mapping in this way:

```
GetMappingsResponse mapping =  restHighLevelClient.indices().getMapping(getMappingsRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);   

mapping.mappings().entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().getSourceAsMap();
```

and this is what I used to get:

```
"properties": {
                "words": {
                    "index": false,
                    "type": "keyword"
                },
                "fileIndex": {
                    "type": "long"
                }
         
}
```

I am trying to get the mapping of my index in new java client , this is what I did:

```
> GetMappingRequest getMappingsRequest = new
> GetMappingRequest.Builder().index
>                     (indexName).build();
> 
> elasticsearchClient.indices().getMapping(getMappingsRequest)
> Map<String, Property> map =
> mapping.result().entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().mappings().properties();
```

but instead of getting only the type per each field I am getting a list of all possible types:
for example:

```
   "mapping": {
            "words": {
                "integer": false,
                "float": false,
                "text": false,
                "object": false,
                "binary": false,
                "long": false,
                "short": false,
                "boolean": false,
                "double": false,
                "alias": false,
                "date": false,
                "dateRange": false,
                "nested": false,
                "histogram": false,
                "ipRange": false,
                "geoShape": false,
                "shape": false,
                "rankFeature": false,
                "wildcard": false,
                "aggregateMetricDouble": false,
                "tokenCount": false,
                "unsignedLong": false,
                "version": false,
                "geoPoint": false,
                "completion": false,
                "halfFloat": false,
                "dynamicProperty": false,
                "flattened": false,
                "constantKeyword": false,
                "floatRange": false,
                "integerRange": false,
                "dateNanos": false,
                "doubleRange": false,
                "denseVector": false,
                "byte": false,
                "matchOnlyText": false,
                "point": false,
                "searchAsYouType": false,
                "longRange": false,
                "murmur3": false,
                "join": false,
                "ip": false,
                "percolator": false,
                "keyword": true,
                "rankFeatures": false,
                "scaledFloat": false
            },
            "fileIndex": {
                "integer": false,
                "float": false,
                "text": false,
                "object": false,
                "binary": false,
                "long": true,
                "short": false,
                "boolean": false,
                "double": false,
                "alias": false,
                "date": false,
                "dateRange": false,
                "nested": false,
                "histogram": false,
                "ipRange": false,
                "geoShape": false,
                "shape": false,
                "rankFeature": false,
                "wildcard": false,
                "aggregateMetricDouble": false,
                "tokenCount": false,
                "unsignedLong": false,
                "version": false,
                "geoPoint": false,
                "completion": false,
                "halfFloat": false,
                "dynamicProperty": false,
                "flattened": false,
                "constantKeyword": false,
                "floatRange": false,
                "integerRange": false,
                "dateNanos": false,
                "doubleRange": false,
                "denseVector": false,
                "byte": false,
                "matchOnlyText": false,
                "point": false,
                "searchAsYouType": false,
                "longRange": false,
                "murmur3": false,
                "join": false,
                "ip": false,
                "percolator": false,
                "keyword": false,
                "rankFeatures": false,
                "scaledFloat": false
            }
}
```

How can I get the mapping as in elasitcsearch 7 , just the type and the index field?

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution, using toString return a string json, then converting it to json:

```
 Map<String, Property> map = mapping.result().entrySet().iterator().next().getValue().mappings().properties();
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();



Map<String, Object> map2=  map.entrySet().stream().
                        collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        e -> e.getKey(),
                        e ->  JsonParser.parseString("{" + e.getValue().toString() + "}")
                                        .getAsJsonObject().get("Property"))
                );
```